# addRule / insertRule with css selectors

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

Is it possible to use addRule or insertRule to also pass id selectors ? 
ie :

```
document.styleSheets[1].addRule('div #3', 'font: 14px verdana');
```

which would create a rule for div ?

Or is there any kind of known work around ?

Comment: Have you tried it?  According to the documentation that I'm looking at, that should work fine - assuming that JavaScript will let you do so with an invalid id.  #3 is invalid because an id must start with a letter.

Comment: I made something that should work for you: https://gist.github.com/yckart/5563717

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the selector is invalid. The ID selector `#3` is invalid because ID selectors [cannot begin with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

To fix this, use an ID which *can* be selected with a *valid* selector, for example `#three`:

```
document.styleSheets[1].addRule('div #three', 'font: 14px verdana');
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could try this method: http://pp19dd.com/2012/01/add-inline-css-or-remote-css-file-with-javascript/

```
function css_add_file( css_url ) {
    var c = document.createElement('link');
    c.type = 'text/css';
    c.rel = 'stylesheet';
    c.href = css_url;
    c.media = 'screen';
    c.title = 'dynamicLoadedSheet';
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c);
}
```

It'll permit you to more or less inject CSS rules without having to micromanage their structure.

Ex: `css_add_inline( "div#three { font-size:14px; font-family: Verdana; }" );`